# Quotient curve of Fermat curve over a finite field (Ireland -Rosen exercise)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, algebraic-curves, exponential-sum

I'm thinking a exercise 12 of Ireland-Rosen "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory" p.226 as follows:[image: the exercise]

But I have no idea, could you give some hints starting from (a) ?